How to write a type-safe decorator (typescript 5 based) factory that can handle both class methods and class field functions?
I‘m creating a Typescript 5 decorator factory to custom the logger for async function in class. It should handle both class method and class field function. But I ran into a type issue where I couldn't leverage function overloading to handle both class methods and class fields.
The first, I try to write a factory only for field function like below:
export function customLoggerForField<
  This extends InstanceWithLoggerMethod,
  T extends (this: This, ...args: any[]) => any,
>(hooks?: {
  onError?: (logger: Logger, error: unknown) => void;
}) {
  function logger (
    target: undefined,
    context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext<This, T>,
  ) {
    const { kind, name } = context;

    if (kind === 'field') {
      return (initialValue: T) => {
        const replacedMethod = async function (this: This, ...args: Parameters<T>) {
          try {
            const response = await initialValue.call(this, ...args);
            return response;
          } catch (error) {
            hooks?.onError?.(this.logger, error);
            throw error;
          }
        } as T;

        return replacedMethod;
      };
    }

    throw new Error(
      `'logger' cannot decorate non-field or non-method properties like ${name as string}.`,
    );
  };

  return logger;
}

It works fine as expected.
class Test {
  logger = () => {};

  @customLoggerForField()
  field = () => {}
}

And then I write a factory only for class method, it looks good too.
export function customLoggerForMethod<
  This extends InstanceWithLoggerMethod,
  T extends (this: This, ...args: any[]) => any,
>(hooks?: {
  onError?: (logger: Logger, error: unknown) => void;
}) {
  function logger (
    target: T,
    context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<This, T>,
  ) {
    const { kind, name } = context;

    if (kind === 'method' && target) {
      const replacedMethod = async function (this: This, ...args: Parameters<T>) {
        try {
          const response = await target.call(this, ...args);
          return response;
        } catch (error) {
          hooks?.onError?.(this.logger, error);
          throw error;
        }
      } as T;

      return replacedMethod;
    }

    throw new Error(
      `'logger' cannot decorate non-field or non-method properties like ${name as string}.`,
    );
  };

  return logger;
}

class Test {
  logger = () => {};

  @customLoggerForMethod()
  method() {}
}

Finally, I try to combine these 2 factory function into one. The following is the more complete code:
type Logger = (...p: any[]) => any;

interface InstanceWithLoggerMethod {
  logger: Logger
}

export function customLogger<
  This extends InstanceWithLoggerMethod,
  T extends (this: This, ...args: any[]) => any,
>(hooks?: {
  onError?: (logger: Logger, error: unknown) => void;
}) {
  function logger(target: T, context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<This, T>): T
  function logger(target: undefined, context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext<This, T>): (initialValue: T) => T
  function logger (
    target: T | undefined,
    context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<This, T> | ClassFieldDecoratorContext<This, T>,
  ) {
    const { kind, name } = context;

    if (kind === 'field') {
      return (initialValue: T) => {
        const replacedMethod = async function (this: This, ...args: Parameters<T>) {
          try {
            const response = await initialValue.call(this, ...args);
            return response;
          } catch (error) {
            hooks?.onError?.(this.logger, error);
            throw error;
          }
        } as T;

        return replacedMethod;
      };
    }

    if (kind === 'method' && target) {
      const replacedMethod = async function (this: This, ...args: Parameters<T>) {
        try {
          const response = await target.call(this, ...args);
          return response;
        } catch (error) {
          hooks?.onError?.(this.logger, error);
          throw error;
        }
      } as T;

      return replacedMethod;
    }

    throw new Error(
      `'logger' cannot decorate non-field or non-method properties like ${name as string}.`,
    );
  };

  return logger;
}

class Test {
  logger = () => {};

  @customLoggerForMethod()
  method() {}

  @customLogger()
  method2() {}

  @customLoggerForField()
  field = () => {}

  @customLogger()
  field2 = () => {}
}

But at this time, a type error occurred on field2 = () => {}:
    Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
      No overload matches this call.
        Overload 1 of 2, '(target: never, context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext<Test, never>): never', gave the following error.
          Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
        Overload 2 of 2, '(target: undefined, context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext<Test, never>): (initialValue: never) => never', gave the following error.
          Argument of type 'ClassFieldDecoratorContext<Test, () => void> & { name: "field2"; private: false; static: false; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ClassFieldDecoratorContext<Test, never>'.
            The types returned by 'access.get(...)' are incompatible between these types.
              Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    'target' is declared but its value is never read.
    'Test' is declared but never used.

I don't know how to resolve it, so how to write a type-safe decorator (typescript5 based) factory that can handle both class methods and class field functions?
Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gcwRATlAvFAFAOj2ALigEMA7EAbQF0BKDAPhPIG4BYAKA4EtThUAzYgGNoASVIBnYGREB1LsAAW8JKgCyEJXAAmUAN4coUADaJkKIivMcAvhw4QAHmDgpgUfgFdSQ4FzikUEKeUnAAtlaoADyGUAAqilwSUE58pNrJ4lIyEPJKkSgaWtoANLFxKY5pGdhKSUQJSSVQeDjEKAgSRGSUtAxMIGXs9FiKcHAA1hIA-EQG7EYBAKIoKK6z2KaqFrBmqM2oazveE6RwAO6kdOiMAG5wXNps7DZ080ZePn4BJnsoWNIOpoGs0hAE+FUiABhYzECQSIpjbQAEQgYJQxGArih4NSUUaEmacXoNAasU+vn8gS25gB7WQwCI3m0EH4PAgpSCuMhUBhcIkADEuBBjCi0a5MdjucB8YlCfESUQsDwFFxiMYAGrqzwQBrXRhxcneSk-GmobCxIyAhkNKAAHygzNZ7NKlq5vFS0Nh8MROlR6MlKBxHqqsqaCvtvO9guFov9EqxQelYflxKGRjebrBknceigEx4nNIxDC0BsGHdEOAzzdXH42AL6Qw6EwAHI2SLtK3MwsjH2UJpPChAsrSKr1VrjDq9f13n359mpFAB2BYSJtL7dJg4SAfB5jd8R3UuvE5c1WvSTwAFdolzSoCT4kn6N3zq0oEAv3tvt+L9wDiQXEkaBt3OYgFCgFU-AnbUIBwIR1WMAEzxaPBLxoZ4fx-AdgCHQIAKAiQIEwrCjHLBDgCERRsEOVwe1I+cxkmGYcGWVZ1hwZCkhwM0UAOdiUAw18sKUNZzhSASSNIuxvzfcs4XiGtZPnHC8OXCBV2EDlNykvsbF0mTa3rLBGy3FsoFbUtilbKAADJbKga1NHo38AiXFc120zQkQrHc9wpQ9ajlBoUIvDpr1vKyHyfFyf2AD8vwY913IgQC3JAkgwIgpzgHgxCuPlMLOiE5S31U4d1LS4DdPncjMSomiBNirCmKmaZWNIFYjnagqeL+fijhKpLRIuCSjhqvThPk5I4iU7DBwqjytI3bydAM+xZJG8TSAgcSutcLBhIAA1bXibIQ0gzncFkAz4KAzlIABaDtRSgVx7oCR6rJ8sA1kgNxhWSYwuAmaAABI9GLUsSGSKQUB4BAbBwI70z7IaoH0jajHK6k-meQz2CcFw3H3L4qSCEIsQiP4BVcIVOxiXsCUqapMhzHI8mUP5N1RipUggdJkgKkLwyKk8emofUBiGEZWpmOZYjY7qlV4yx+rG1wmVIU4Liufp7kefGXIC8neItTb6WBR10mdHbXVk7Mqy9fl6bjcUMUTYMqxTIl6FR5q-30fNC2aKGywrR3Ujmvs6wbQtmzbF6u2a7GFpHKC1U1WCZxuRKsMDpb103XyJF3IRSZNI9gtPUW0PCogbwxKKUEfYkU7feLPznJKC9SwiMuILL3AzmCpzghDjCQ49zzr4qJvm3DFr79L570oJ6uorBaMEvOkrl9qlY43reIGujV-nLaNZQc+MeEsiYcUrGsJx9TNKL1anim9bOE2xQxPu3aUB9r-GOqdP450yBXSgDdBM0AHrPVjLod68Dvo6CgL9OA-0-CpRMCDcGkM7wPzhgjJGKM3To0xj-VOi9cbbHxhtImrh3Amx+MEUI1Nti00KB-RmRhmb80FlALI0gfC5AUFzbYPNygswFjUYWNdCqz3FuQSW-Qegy1GOMNqCteyHxQBsLAqtdjbFPscbWZxLhSwNp-F4xsDymz+ObC+ltGTxFRkYSOPI+Q+g-vGD2UoQwygJL7f2u9kq5mDukUOhDyyYE8dWJ+RhY4mXji2NsqCux2Qcjlduvc35eWKCXMuFdAryOCahNo9coCNzvHwFuMUwkXwSt3fObl-zL2Ar5IejkXF5UngVGelS55337GnSq-dV51Uopvbe7dGJaJYnonqx4+omKvujUil9t6TKmg-WaiTRk0Nfp5FaxRv5ukvjtPaAlDqlROmddel04DXXdpiOBn0k5vTQCgj+6C-qoGwUDPBUAIZhyIfFEhyN3FQAodHF+vF6E-yENGeIqVcyxDNpgLAUs9CUNiAAATYVTAoXDNzYtiBk7F+gCZGEJZTcIBRyW9gyQAJipbip+dL2EkrpogplHxEEVipbnDlVCoBcuJX8flHhEEsqFTimSNggA
